# The 'status' start tag on line 1 does not match the end tag of 'job-request-id'. Line 1, position 1171

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the above error code for following line of code.

```
 XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
 xdoc.LoadXml(smsreport.CampaignXML);//catches exception on this line
```

And

```
smsreport.CampaignXML="
    <job-status-report>
        <job-request-id>
            <recipients>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>4122985372
                    <status>SENT
                    <error-message></error-message>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>8142799046
                    <status>SENT
                    <error-message></error-message>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>4123893743
                    <status>SENT
                    <error-message></error-message>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>8142443845
                    <status>SENT
                    <error-message></error-message>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>4124014618
                    <status>SENT
                    <error-message></error-message>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>4126546500
                    <status>FAIL
                    <error-message>DLVtst:SubmitSM invalid destination address</error-message>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>4129151665
                    <status>SENT
                    <error-message></error-message>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>9712229387
                    <status>SENT
                    <error-message></error-message>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>5708815785
                    <status>SENT
                    <error-message></error-message>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>8183356585
                    <status>SENT
                    <error-message></error-message>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>4124775849
                    <status>SENT
                    <error-message></error-message>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>4124775849
                    <status>SENT
                    <error-message></error-message>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>7169831368
                    <status>SENT
                    <error-message></error-message>
                <recipient>
                    <destination>2022858850
                    <status>SENT
                    <error-message></error-message>
        </job-request-id>
    </job-status-report>"
```

I have also verified that campaignxml is valid xml.How to fix this??

Comment: No, *structurally* the text *resembles* XML, but it is *not* valid XML. That's exactly what the error message is telling you. The *only* end tags in there are `</error-message>` (multiple times) and `</job-request-id>` and `</job-status-report>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reformatted your XML so that it is easier to see what it looks like.

You are missing end tags for most of your elements.

Comment: Yes,That was invalid xml.Thanks andrew.